# How can I remove product link from order details page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to disable the product link under the my orders details table in my account page. I don't want the user to click to product and go to the product page.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the following very simple code snippet, to remove the product permalink from order details page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'display_product_image_in_order_item', 20, 3 );
function display_product_image_in_order_item( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    return $item->get_name();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.