# Make 'item' hyperlink in WooCommerce orders (backend) unclickable for shop manager

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using [How can I remove product link from order details page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64579445/11987538) answer code

However, I've tried this code and placed it on `functions.php`, but it does not work, and this is not for backend.

Is there any specific custom code to be placed in `functions.php`? for only shop manager to disable the order item's link? It can be non-clickable or it will redirect to the page like 'no access' for shop manager. Because I do not want shop manager have the access to the product page and edit the details of product which they can only view the items.

For better reference the item order is at here: https://snipboard.io/uK28js.jpg
[image]

Comment: Any help on this case?

Answer (score 0):

An update on the alternative solution using [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin.

To specify for a user role, may untick all 'Posts' (refer to the image below), to prevent a role (backend) to access the link to edit the product. This applies to the user role who doesn't want the user role to have complete access to the product page. Where they only can see the product name with SKU (if have) without access to edit product page.

[image]

After update the role, and under woocommerce > orders > click on order item
[image]

It will shows 'Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item'

[image]

Feel free to add answer asides from this.

Answer (score -1):

If you want you can do it by editing plugin file

```
woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\views\html-order-item.php
```

here you'll see the hyperlink
change this line:

```
echo $product_link ? '<a href="' . esc_url( $product_link ) . '" class="wc-order-item-name">' . wp_kses_post( $item->get_name() ) . '</a>' : '<div class="wc-order-item-name">' . wp_kses_post( $item->get_name() ) . '</div>';
```

Just remove the  tag

Comment: **NEVER edit core files!** When WC gets updated, it overwrites the installation with any new updates included in the release. If the core has been chopped up and modified beforehand, it’ll wipe out those changes. That means big sections of the installation will just stop working. Modifying the core can have all kinds of unintended consequences, like preventing updates from working correctly, further screwing up an installation. Even worse is the potential to introduce unintended security vulnerabilities. Messing with core files could easily introduce a hole allowing hackers to take over a site

Comment: This is what I'm afraid of too. I believe there's another way to do it, but I've been finding the solution for a long time but still couldn't find it.